# Cache or save files to disc in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Im building a touch application and thinking on making it in Silverlight, previously i used only WPF for this but now im thinking on going with Silverlight.

In WPF i cache movies, music and HD images on disk so i dont have to stream them each time (its for a educational piece of software). Is this approach possible in Silverlight? or are there any alternatives in Silverlight? The data can range from 10Mg to 2Gb.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to cache them in [Isolated storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28VS.95%29.aspx) as you do not have direct access to the Hard Drive in browser mode (non-elevated permissions).

The default Quota for Isolated Storage is only 1MB, but apparently there is no upper limit on [what you can request](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2008/08/14/silverlight-isolated-storage-maximum-quota.aspx) in recent versions of Silverlight.

*The [increase request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.increasequotato%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) will popup a dialog for the user asking permission to increase the space available, but this only has to happen once*

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There are few ways to do this:

**Silverlight 3, 4:**

These versions of silverlight have restricted access to a file system. You can save only to [Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). As its size is 1 MB, you should ask a user to increase its quota. [More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.increasequotato%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).
Also you have access to MyDocuments, MyMusic, MyPictures, and MyVideos folders in trusted application. It is an application that you configure to require elevated trust.

**Silverlight 5:**

In this version you have unlimited access to the local file system in trusted application. [More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#file_system_access).